Unable to use Blazor two-side bind
I'm developing a blazor server app and I have created a component which contains two textfield and a select(I'm using ant design blazor, I think it isn't the cause of the error).
ProfileInfoInput.razor
@inject Toolbelt.Blazor.I18nText.I18nText I18nText
@inject UserService _userService
<InputChunk @bind-Value="@InternalValue.name" placeHolder="@name" tip="@name" />
<br />
<p>@type :</p>
<Select DataSource="@supportTypes"
        @bind-Value="@InternalValue.type"
        ItemValue="c=>c.TypeCode"
        ItemLabel="c=>c.TypeDisplay"
        DefaultValue="@("csharp_remote")"/>
<br />
<InputChunk placeHolder="@endpoint" @bind-Value="@InternalValue.endpoint" tip="@endpoint" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public ProfileInfo Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string name{ get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string type{ get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string endpoint { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<ProfileInfo> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private ProfileInfo InternalValue
    {
        get => Value;
        set
        {
            if (Value != value)
            {
                Value = value;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            }
        }
    }
    private List<ProfileType> supportTypes = new()
    {
        new ProfileType("csharp_remote","Remote CSharp OpenBMCLAPI")
    };

}

and ProfileInfo.cs
    public interface IProfile
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string endpoint { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProfileInfo : IProfile
    {
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Endpoint")]
        public string endpoint { get; set; }

    }

Only one property thew an exception. When I use a two-side bind:
<Blazor_OpenBMCLAPI.Components.ProfileInfoInput name="@i18n["name"]"  endpoint="@i18n["endpoint"]" type="@i18n["type"]" @bind-Value=@addInfo />
It threw:RZ9991    The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-Value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.
I dont't know why for I completely copy the codes from a similar component from my project. The other component and page work well.
Any help are appreciated!

You can't do binding in the way you are attempting to.  I've re-written your control to demonstrate one way to do it.
I don't have AntDesign so I'm using the standard simple controls.  I've added commentary in the code.
<h3>ProfileEditor</h3>

<label class="form-label">Name</label>
<InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_value.name" @bind-Value:after="this.OnAfterChange" />

<label class="form-label">Type</label>
<InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_value.type" @bind-Value:after="this.OnAfterChange" />

<label class="form-label">EndPoint</label>
<InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_value.endpoint" @bind-Value:after="this.OnAfterChange" />

@code {
    // Internal record to track the current data state
    // A record is a value object so we can do equality checking to check for mutation
    private record Model(string? Name, string? Type, string? Endpoint);

    [Parameter] public ProfileInfo? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<ProfileInfo> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private ProfileInfo _value = new();
    private Model? _currentmodel;
    private Model? _changeModel => new(this.Value?.name, this.Value?.type, this.Value?.endpoint);

    // Do the internal assignments here before any rendering takes place
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Call first - sets the component properties to the supplied parameters
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.Value);

        // check if the parameter Value has changed
        if (_value != this.Value)
        {
            _value = this.Value;
            _currentmodel = new(this.Value.name, this.Value.type, this.Value.endpoint);
            // Do any resets such as resetting the edit context
        }

        // Call base with an empty ParameterView
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    // Called whenever a bind change happens.  Detects value changes and calls ValueChanged when necessary
    private void OnAfterChange()
    {
        // Compares the two value objects to detect any changes from the last edit cycle
        if (_changeModel != _currentmodel)
        {
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
            _currentmodel = _changeModel;
        }
    }
}

And the Demo page:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<ProfileEditor @bind-Value="_profile" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Name: @_profile.name</pre>
    <pre>Type: @_profile.type</pre>
    <pre>EndPoint: @_profile.endpoint</pre>
</div>

@code{
    private ProfileInfo _profile = new() { name="Fred"};
}


What is the Model refers to? I can't find the class.

And, however, another control use the same way to bind threw no exception, I don't know why

Model is an internal Record object to track state - I've moved it to the top of the code section.

"another control use the same way to bind threw no exception".  Did it work properly?  Without seeing the code I can't comment.  In the code you've shown the setter on InternalValue doesn't detect internal changes in the class, just a change in the reference to the class instance.  That's the purpose of my Model in the answer.  It's a value object, so we can use equality checks to detect changes without using individual getter/setters on the class object.

the exception still exists after I modified my project as what you said

I probably should have asked the basic questions first. Net version? Interactivity type? Interactivity location?  And what is InputChunk?

All right. I don't want to use this component for it's too complex. I'll use native components instead. Thanks for your help.
